# touchpad does not work in HP Pavilion X2 tablet

Tags: laptop, touchpad, hp, synaptic

I just installed the last version of ubuntu 64 bits in this tablet that had the windows 8. All seems alright including the toucscreen but the touchpad does not work. How to solve this? I tried to follow the commands suggested in other posts about synaptic toucpad but it did not solve the problem.
Can anyone help me? Thank you.

root@Sardas:~# cat /proc/bus/input/devices
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0005 Version=0000
N: Name="Lid Switch"
P: Phys=PNP0C0D/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=1

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0C/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=LNXPWRBN/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab41
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event3 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=20000 20 0 0 1500f02140003 3803078f900d401 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HP Wireless hotkeys"
P: Phys=hpq6001/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=rfkill kbd event5 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=80000000000000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=1bcf Product=2c59 Version=1003
N: Name="HP TrueVision Full HD"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-3.1/button
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3.1/1-3.1:1.0/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event6 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=1bcf Product=2c5a Version=1003
N: Name="HP TrueVision Full HD Rear"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-4.1/button
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4.1/1-4.1:1.0/input/input7
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event7 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=04f3 Product=0193 Version=0110
N: Name="ELAN Touchscreen"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-4.4/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4.4/1-4.4:1.0/input/input10
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event8 
B: PROP=2
B: EV=b
B: KEY=400 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=3273800000000003

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HP WMI hotkeys"
P: Phys=wmi/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input9
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event9 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=33
B: KEY=4000000000 0 1000700000000 2100400 0 0
B: MSC=10
B: SW=22

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input12
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event10 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input15
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event11 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Headphone"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input14
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event12 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=4

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Mic"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input13
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event13 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=10

But doing dmesg appear:
[    2.205571] usb 1-4.2: New USB device found, idVendor=06cb, idProduct=2239
[    2.205579] usb 1-4.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.205583] usb 1-4.2: Product: Synaptics Touch Pad V 103u5

Comment: Please give details, ex.w hat tablet is it?

Comment: HP X2 11-H003 N3510. It is a detachable laptop. So the screen part is a tablet (or a tablet with attachable keyboard)

Comment: the touchpad does not appear anywhere doing cat /proc/bus/input/devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2222243

I follow the suggestion of shane-u (last entry) to update kernel:

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.15-rc5-utopic/linux-headers-3.15.0-031500rc5-generic_3.15.0-031500rc5.201405091635_amd64.deb

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.15-rc5-utopic/linux-headers-3.15.0-031500rc5_3.15.0-031500rc5.201405091635_all.deb

wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.15-rc5-utopic/linux-image-3.15.0-031500rc5-generic_3.15.0-031500rc5.201405091635_amd64.deb

dpkg -i linux-headers-3.15.0-*.deb linux-image-3.15.0-*.deb

Then a Shutdown and then reboot (do not do a restart).

ATTENTION: i got the last kernel versions here:
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D